# What does the parameters without arrows mean in type constructor?

Tags: haskell, type-constructor

In the expression

```
data Frank a b = Frank {frankField :: b a} deriving (Show)
```

What does `{frankField :: b a}` means?

Is `{frankField :: b a}` a type constructor? If so, should the parameters look like `b->a` instead `b a`?

Comment: If `b` is `Maybe`, not `Maybe Int`, but `Maybe`, and `a` is `Int`, then what is `b a`?

Comment: That's called a "record". Usually you see multiple fields like `data T = K { one :: Int , two :: String , three :: [Bool] }`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Frank` is a type of kind `* -> (* -> *) -> *`, that is, it takes a type `a` (of kind `*`) such as `Int`, `Char`, or `String`; and a unary type *constructor* `b` (of kind `* -> *`) such as `Maybe` or `Either String`. (You can check the kind of a type using the `:kind` or `:k` command in GHCi.)

It has one constructor, also named `Frank`, which contains one *field* (not a constructor) of type `b a` called `frankField`—for example, the type of `frankField` in a value of type `Frank Int Maybe` is `Maybe Int`, since `b` = `Maybe` and `a` = `Int`, so `b a` = `Maybe Int`.

This definition is using *record* notation to give a name to the field—you could also have written just `data Frank a b = Frank (b a)` to leave it anonymous, but the advantage of naming the field is that you can use explicit record syntax to construct a `Frank` value:

```
frank1 :: Frank Int Maybe
frank1 = Frank { frankField = Just 1 }
```

Or to modify a value:

```
frank2 :: Frank Int Maybe
frank2 = frank1 { frankField = Nothing }
```

Or access the field by name:

```
value :: Maybe Int
value = frankField frank1
```

This is more convenient, and more common, when a constructor includes multiple fields; also, you’ll typically see `newtype` instead of `data` when a type wraps only a single value, since `newtype` has less overhead and slightly different laziness semantics.